# Is there a way to know the GPL or LGPL exact version of external libraries compiled with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Wanted to compile external libraries like x264, x265, opencore-amr, libogg,libvpx, etc. with FFmpeg. Some of these libraries have GPL and LGPL licenses but I could not find which version of GPL or LGPL exactly. There are two flags we can pass during FFmpeg compilation: --enable-gpl and --enable-version3. If I compile FFmpeg without --enable-version3 will it always mean that GPL and LGPL versions are below version 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`LICENSE.md`](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=LICENSE.md):

---

Should you, for whatever reason, prefer to use version 3 of the (L)GPL, then
the configure parameter `--enable-version3` will activate this licensing option for you. Read the file `COPYING.LGPLv3` or, if you have enabled GPL parts, `COPYING.GPLv3` to learn the exact legal terms that apply in this case.

The following libraries are under GPL version 2:

- avisynth
- frei0r
- libcdio
- libdavs2
- librubberband
- libvidstab
- libx264
- libx265
- libxavs
- libxavs2
- libxvid

The following libraries are under LGPL version 3:

- gmp
- libaribb24
- liblensfun

When combining them with FFmpeg, use the configure option `--enable-version3` to upgrade FFmpeg to the LGPL v3.

The VMAF, mbedTLS, RK MPI, OpenCORE and VisualOn libraries are under the Apache License 2.0. That license is incompatible with the LGPL v2.1 and the GPL v2, but not with version 3 of those licenses. So to combine these libraries with FFmpeg, the license version needs to be upgraded by passing `--enable-version3` to configure.

The smbclient library is under the GPL v3, to combine it with FFmpeg,
the options `--enable-gpl` and `--enable-version3` have to be passed to configure to upgrade FFmpeg to the GPL v3.